# Find nth Instance in Array in Excel with Multiple Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match, array-formulas

I am attempting to create a table in excel that contains all of the rows that meet certain criteria on a separate table. As of now, the formula below works for just one criterion, but I need to have it adapted to suit at least two criteria.

```
{=INDEX(tbl[Entry ID],SMALL(IF(tbl[Title]="Manager",ROW(tbl[Title])-ROW(INDEX(tbl[Title],1,1))+1),[@nth]))}
```

tbl is a separate table containing the ID and Title information. As an example, I need to have this adapted to show all of the criteria where tbl[Title]="Manager" AND tbl[Region]="USA".

Comment: Use vba to filter,copy visible and paste, or use an advanced filter. You would need to have a table the same size as the original and show blanks at the bottom with formula as formula cannot add or remove lines to the table.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to modify your formula is `IF((tbl[Title]="Manager")*(tbl[Region]="USA"),...`

```
{ =INDEX(tbl[Entry ID],SMALL(IF((tbl[Title]="Manager") * (tbl[Region]="USA"),
  ROW(tbl[Title])-ROW(INDEX(tbl[Title],1,1))+1),[@nth]))}
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```